# Using a batch to sort through a complex of folders and sort any files with a specific string in their name to a specific directory?

Tags: sorting, input, batch-file, find

So I have a collection of art from the internet; it is very large and spans an extreme amount of subdirectories under the main folder I keep it all under (entitled Uda). I've built up this collection over a period of about 4 years. In the most recent 2 years, I've been organising things I save by artist (most of this comes from the site DeviantArt if it matters). But I have 2 years' worth of files unsorted, all over the place and I'd like to sort them.

I figure this is an ideal time to practice some batch scripting, but... I've not the faintest idea where to start. Google hasn't been very helpful, it's too hard to explain what I want to do in one question, let alone find someone who has needed the same thing and been guided through it. Also, I'd honestly much prefer to pull apart and figure out an already-made script to understand it and learn from it (that's how I tend to learn best).

So can anyone help me? If you don't understand what I want to do: 
I wish to make a script where I can input something (i.e. an artist's name) and have a folder made for it under a certain directory (no matter where the batch is being run from or the files drawn from) with the name of the term that was entered, and then all files under another directory with that term found and moved.

For the record, even if I weren't interested in batch scripting, I couldn't use Windows Explorer to search for them all then cut them because I disabled it (for personal reasons).

Comment: bite the bullet, learn a scripting language from scratch. Then the problem will basically solve itself.

Comment: That's like telling someone to just 'learn Japanese' if they asked for help deconstructing a sentence. It's not so easy for everyone, and everyone learns differently. I myself learn best through deconstruction.

Comment: I personally can't see how you can "learn" from an existing script without learning the basics first. But given that nobody is likely to do what you want (write/give you a script that does what you want) this will be the path to follow at stack.

Comment: The same way one might dissect an animal to see how its internal organs work; in order to understand something I like to break it down and figure out how each piece works by looking over it all and thinking.

Comment: I'm glad you have a method that works for you. Typically people post questions that have code in them so that others may help with specific problems in that code. You may find it more productive to attempt a solution, then post a problem you have in that solution. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Well see I've been trying to make something for people to work off with me, but I can't even find/figure out how to get it to prompt for input or anything. I'm finding all these solutions to people's problems that are context-sensitive, but nothing broad that anyone could use for any kind of script and adapt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: Note that SPACES are significant in simple SET statements
:: Set relative or local root (start-point of subtree to scan)
:: Use normal then safemethod 1 then safemethod2 - all do the same thing
:: Note : from the prompt,
:: command /?
:: will generally show help...
SET relroot=c:\wherever
(SET relroot=c:\wherever)
SET "relroot=c:\wherever"
:: repeat for destination directory
SET "destdir=c:\destination"
::
:: Read Artist
:: Make sure ARTISTS has no existing value, then prompt for input
::
:again
(SET artist=)
SET /p artist="Artist ? "
::
:: Check for input, exit if none
:: Note :EOF is a special predefined label meaning "END OF FILE"
:: character case is generally insignificant
::
IF NOT DEFINED artist GOTO :eof
::
:: make a new directory
:: the 2>nul suppresses an error message like 'it already exists'
:: In quotes in case variables contain spaces
MD "%destdir%\%artist%" 2>nul
::
:: Now look for filenames containing the data entered
:: Note: here, the metavariable %%i IS Case-sensitive
:: >nul means 'don't show message like '1 file(s) moved'
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ( 
   ' dir /s /b /a-d "%relroot%\*%artist%*" '
   ) DO (
 ECHO %%i
 IF EXIST "%destdir%\%artist%\%%~nxi" (
    ECHO Cannot MOVE "%%i" because "%destdir%\%artist%\%%~nxi" exists
 ) else (ECHO MOVE "%%i" "%destdir%\%artist%\%%~nxi" >nul)
)

GOTO again
```

Well, here's a starter script - assuming that artists' names are in the filename.

Most of the documentation is in-line.

Note that the `::...` form of documentation is actually a broken-label and is inadvisable within loops and parenthesised code generally - use REM there. It is however easier to type and less intrusive

The `FOR` loop needs a little explanation: much of it can be deciphered with a bit of persistence from the documentation

```
for /?
```

from the prompt. But the heads-up is:

`for /f` reads a "file" line-by-line and applies each successive line to the metavariable after being tokenised between delimiters. You can specify the tokens by number counting from 1 and the delimiters are any characters appearing between the `delims=` and the closing quote. Default delimiters are [space],[tab],[comma],[semicolon] and default tokens is `1`. "delims=" specifies that there are no delimiters, so the entire line is applied to the metavariable.

It's possible to use this facility on a data line like `Wed. 07/11/2012` by using `FOR/f "tokens=2,3,4delims=/ " %%i in...` to apply `07` to `%%i`, `11` to `%%j` and `2012` to `%%k` - the tokens are `Wed.`,`07`,`11` and `2012` when the line is tokenised using [either space or `/`] and the 2nd token is applied to the loop metavariable `%%i`, the third to `%%j` and so on through the list of token numbers. The special token "`*`" means 'the rest of the line following the highest-number token nominated'

AND.. a single-quoted "filename" is the output of a command. `dir /s /b /a-d "%relroot%\*%artist%*"` is the directorylist in `/b` basic form (filenames only) `/s` scan subdirectories `/a-d` but don't mention <s>the war</s> directorynames starting at %relroot% and having %artist% somewhere in the filename - all quoted in case spaces are present.

Comment: This worked for the most part, but it didn't move all the files it found to the directory it created.

Comment: How about not keeping those filenames secret? Can't fix it with a response properly "it didn't work - now guess why"

Comment: Well, I entered 'metalforever' for the artist, and it found jpg, png, gif and swf files (those are all the right types). Could the name of the file really have an effect on the performance of the batch?

Comment: Probably not. The question is, what was the FULL name of the file? It was no doubt reported. Batch programming is an impresise science. **WARNING*** I've edited the above batch. If you MOVE a [filename] to a directory where [filename] is already present, the MOVEd file REPLACES the existing.

Comment: Well there were lots of files, that's the thing. Many, many files. I couldn't list them all here. I've tried the revised version, it was much faster than the last for some reason, but still nothing was moved.

Comment: Ah - by "didn't move all the files" you mean "didn't move ANY OF the files" not "moved some but not others"? It's standard practice to simply `ECHO` the **PROPOSED** instruction rather than **EXECUTE** the instruction. That way, problems have a better chance of being detected before any damage is done. If you cut the keyword `ECHO` from the line ` ) else (ECHO MOVE "%...` then the `MOVE` will be executed. The downside is that the `>nul` in the line should have suppressed the message `ECHO`ed (and hence not executed). If the `ECHO` is removed, `MOVE` will display "1 file(s) moved"

Comment: for each file moved, and the way to suppress this message is to include the `>nul`. So - if the line has `ECHO` then remove the `>nul` to get a list of the **PROPOSED** `MOVE`s. If the `ECHO` is removed, the `MOVE` is executed and you *NEED* the `>nul` to suppress the "1 file(s) moved" message. Best to test by using a small subtree - copy a few files to a dummy subdirectory as `relroot`. That way, there will be a quick test that's not going to generate a huge amount of output to swamp you.

Comment: What you said makes sense, but I just tested it without the echo and I still didn't get flooded with "1 file(s) moved" messages. But it works now, which is good. So is it then possible to have it skip over certain filetypes then? For the sake of example, gif and swf files?

Comment: By the way, sorry about the misunderstanding, I wasn't clear.

Comment: Programmers generally get satisfaction solving problems. A side-effect is that they start thinking like compoters and become a little pedantic about semantics - like, er, computers. So - problem solved, but now we need to fiter `gif` and `swf`. Easy to do - and demonstrates why you use `ECHO` to test... Change the `' dir /s /b...` line by adding `^|findstr /i /v ".gif .swf"` between the `st%*"` and the closing `'` This "pipes" the output of the `dir` command to a `findstr` command which `/v`=EXCLUDES names containing ".swf" OR ".gif" the `/i` makes this case-insensitive

Comment: At the prompt, see `findstr /?` for documentation. The caret (`^`) before the pipe (`|`) tells the processor that the pipe is **part** of the command to be executed, and doesn't have its normal meaning to THIS instance of the processor.

Comment: A month later and looking back upon those last two comments in my spare time I finally realise what you mean xD 
And now I feel thick. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I wont write it for you but, but here is a list of roughly the things you have to achieve. Try looking for each of those and then combine them

1. input a name
2. create a directory with this name
3. find the files with this name
4. move found files to the directory

if you post code of what you are trying i'll gladly help you.

Comment: Appreciated :) 
But I can't seem to find an appropriate method of prompting for the input anywhere I look... So it'll be a little bit before I have anything to work with.